# Problem with docker-compose, nginx and specified location

Tags: nginx, docker, alpine-linux

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '2' 
services: 
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.11.8-alpine
        ports:
          - "8081:80"
        volumes:
          - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html
          - ./html:/myapp
          - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
          - ./error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And this is `site.conf`

```
server {

   listen 8081;
   index index.html index.php;
   server_name localhost;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   location /html {
       root /myapp;
   }
}
```

It works on `http://nginx-php-docker.local:8081/`, showing the file `index.html` which is inside the `/code` folder.

But It is not working with `http://nginx-php-docker.local:8081/html`

The error log is

```
2017/01/13 08:50:27 [error] 7#7: 
  *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/html" failed (2: No such file or directory), 
    client: 172.19.0.1, 
    server: localhost, 
    request: "GET /html HTTP/1.1", 
    host: "nginx-php-docker.local:8081"
```

Comment: How does your nginx.conf look like?

Comment: @rckrd It is very simple https://gist.github.com/anhducbkhn/21f2a35db1d9dfb5cbe089f658e36c3f

Answer (score 9):

You are configuring the nginx container to listen on port 8081 in `site.conf`, this makes no sense since the image exposes port 80 and 443.

Change your `site.conf` to:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   index index.html index.php;
   server_name localhost;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
   location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

   location /html {
      alias /myapp;
   }
}
```

And the following line in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:  
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: I got another issue with mysql container, please help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671935/php-cannot-connect-to-mysql-in-docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

Edit you'r compose file to be like this ,, you are redirecting the html file to the wrong directory

```
version: '2' 

services: 

nginx:

image: nginx:1.11.8-alpine
ports:
  - "8081:80"
volumes:
  - ./code:/var/www/html/
  - ./html:/myapp
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  - ./error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score -3):

In your terminal run the command:

```
sudo setenfonce 0
```

Now, re-run the docker command.