# php cannot connect to mysql in docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose

```html
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11.8-alpine
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./html:/myapp
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    links:
      - phpfpm
  phpfpm:
    image: php7-fpm:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      -  ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html
    links:
      - db_mysql
  db_mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.17
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    # restart: no
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp2017
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp2017
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Here is how I build my own php7-fpm:lastest

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

I cannot connect to mysql container

```
$serverName = 'localhost';
$userName = 'wp';
$password = 'wp2017';
$dbName = 'wp2017';

$link = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $dbName);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
```

I always get error: "
    Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in   /usr/share/nginx/html/db.php on line 8
Connect failed: No such file or directory"

Where I run command 
    sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :3306

I get this
    tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      15362/docker-proxy

Please help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi

Comment: Would try to use your local IP for connection at first.

Comment: I also cannot connect.
I installed a mysql server in local  ( Ubuntu 14.04 ) but I  already stop it.
Seems it is reason ?

Comment: are you sure mysqli is installed properly? have a look at the phpinfo if it is running

Comment: Could be a solution. A mysql-server needs to be running to connect to it. :P

Comment: @Pingbeat yes, I checked http://imgur.com/a/r7jMA

Comment: But the mysqli-server is running when you try to connect, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, it is working  http://imgur.com/kJU9QyO

Comment: @Pingbeat it is working for me now.
Here is what I fixed

$serverName = 'db_mysql:3306'; // not localhost, 127.0.0.1...

Comment: glad you found a solution

Answer (score 22):

Change PHP script

```
$serverName = 'db_mysql';
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks this helped, but why is that? Because the name in the docker file is mysql? So if I wanted to connect to localhost I should've name it localhost?

Comment: You can give it a name like `container_name: yourname` and then use it instead of a localhost and it should work.